# How to call this function in main() in cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the following remove() function in the main() function. Please let me know what is wrong with my current code.

```
void remove(float a[], int& n, int i);
int main() {
    float a[]={56.8, 14.2, 0.2, 22.3, 3.3, 54.02, 543.33, 456,333, 1.1};
    int size, del;
    size =sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    cout<<"Enter the element to be deleted!";
    cin >>del;
    cout << "Removed= "<< remove(a, size, del) << "\n";
}

void remove(float a[], int& n, int i){
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        a[j-1] = a[j];
     --n;
    }
```

Comment: `remove` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything, hence nothing is sent to `cout`

Comment: change the datatype of remove from void to float and add return statement

Comment: @PiNaKa30 I get the "Control reaches end of non-void function"  error message for the last line when compiling the code.

Comment: Did you add the return statement? You need to first store a[i] in some variable before your for loop and return it after for loop

Comment: @PiNaKa30 isn't there another way to do the same without altering the function code?

Comment: Then instead of returning, remove the `cout` statement from main function and just call the function normally, i.e. `remove(a, size, del)`. Then in remove function, write `cout << "Removed= "<< a[i] << "\n";` before the for loop.

Comment: I still have the same error: "Control reaches end of non-void function"

Comment: @developer that error is referring to the int main() function itself, add a ```return 0``` to the int main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is

> a) let me know what is wrong with my code

and

> b) isn't there another way to do the same without altering the function code

to a)

1. I learned recently not to use namespace if possible because of the high chance to get avoidable errors due to variable naming that actually happened very often - so `std::` is recommended instead of [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=not%20using%20namespace%20std)
2. `sizeof()` may use internally double not float so beside it works my warning: `implicit conversion loses floating-point precision: 'double' to 'float'`
3. A for - slope with more than one line in the body should be written in brackets else my warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   20 |     for (int j=i+1; j
4. If you use `std::cin` always should be checking for wrong input e.g. like I did with the `input()` function.
5. Since `int main(){return 0;}` is a function and the "int" indicates a return value, always close the function with a "return 0" for a stop signal to your OS.
6. Declaring the variables at the beginning instead between the lines makes the code more readable
7. Also please don't forget check your Question as solved if you got a proper answer to avoid it showing up in the "unsolved" section of stackoverflow.com ;)

to b)

yes, it is - just besides using the  { } - brackets like so:

```
#include <iostream> //std, std::cin
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()

int input(int size); //int signals return
void remove(double a[], int& n, int i); //void signals no return

int main() {

    int size, del;
    double rem;

    double a[]={56.8, 14.2, 0.2, 22.3, 3.3, 54.02, 543.33, 456,333, 1.1};
    size =sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    std::cout<<"Which element do you want to remove: ";
    del = input(size); //check the input

    rem = a[del]; //filling rem to print out the value to be removed to not change the function like you asked for
    std::cout << "Removed= " << rem << std::endl; 
    remove(a, size, del); 

return 0;
}

void remove(double a[], int& n, int i)
{
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
       {
        a[j-1] = a[j];
        --n;
       }
}

int input(int size)
{
    int input;

    while (!(std::cin >> input) || input < 0 || input >= size) {
         std::cin.clear();
         std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
         std::cout << "invalid input ignored; try again and enter a valid move between -1 and " << size << "\n";
        }

    return input;
}
```

My intention is for everyone including myself to learn even from seemingly easy questions. I hope I reached my goal for you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
float remove(float a[], int& n, int i);
int main() {
    float a[]={56.8, 14.2, 0.2, 22.3, 3.3, 54.02, 543.33, 456,333, 1.1};
    int size, del;
    size =sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    cout<<"Which element do you want to remove: ";
    cin >>del;
    remove (a, size, del);
}

float remove(float a[], int& n, int i){
    cout << "Removed= "<< a[i] << "\n";
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        a[j-1] = a[j];
        --n;
    return i;
    }
```

Comment: A better return value would be `a[i]` (saved before the deletion loop) instead of just `i`, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
float remove(float a[], int& n, int i){
    float deleted = a[i]; 
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        a[j-1] = a[j];
     --n;
    return deleted;
}
```

Comment: Would be a *far* better answer if you had `float deleted = a[i]` - and declared the `remove` function as `float`.

Answer (score -1):

Add return statement in remove function and change return type accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you mean to add the return function to the original code in the question or to the changed code as mentioned in the comments?

Comment: your answer is too vague